# Super() in abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, super

I have the following program :

```
public abstract class geometricFigure {
    private int dim1, dim2;

    public geometricFigure(int dim1, int dim2) {
        super();
        this.dim1 = dim1;
        this.dim2 = dim2;
    }

    public geometricFigure() {
        this.dim1 = 0;
        this.dim2 = 0;
    }
}
```

I am struggling to understand, what does the `super()` method in the parameterized constructor do. I can see here that this abstract class doesn't extend any class and I have difficulties into understanding what `super()` method from what superclass does it call.

Btw. This class is extended by two other classes called `Echilateral Triangle` and `Circle`.

```
public class echilateralTriangle extends geometricFigure {
    public echilateralTriangle() {
        super(1, 1);
    }

    public echilateralTriangle(int dim1, int dim2) {
        super(dim1, dim2);
    }
}
```

**Circle class:**

```
public class Circle extends geometricFigure {
    public Circle() {
        super(1, 1);
    }

    public Circle(int dim1, int dim2) {
        super(dim1, dim2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every class in Java extends `Object` even your `geometricFigure`

Comment: Remember that there is the [`Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), so I would assume that even if your abstract class doesn't explicitly extend any class, the `super()` call would still end up there eventually.

Comment: `super()` calls the no-argument constructor of the superclass (`Object` in your case). This is automatically added to any constructor that doesn't contain a call to `super()` or `this()` by the compiler.

Comment: Use standard naming conventions.  Class names should start with uppercase letters.  Following convention make reading your source easier for everyone.

Comment: So it's calling the constructor from the 'Object' class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the answer you got. Also, to the downvoters: isn't this an interesting and valid question? Sure, obvious to most of you, but still interesting to others.

Comment: Ok but if the parametrized constructor of 'geometricFigure' instantiate the variables 'dim1' and 'dim2', why is there any need of calling the 'super()' method a.k.a. default constructor of 'Object' class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` calls the parent class' constructor with the arguments passed to it. In this case, `super()` calls the parent's no-arg constructor. A class that doesn't explicitly declare its parent implicitly extends `Object`, so here `super()` will call `Object`'s default constructor, which it would also do implicitly had the call been omitted. So it's not wrong, just redundant.